# Is it ok to assume that MSMQ will never crash itself

Tags: c#, windows, msmq, windows-server

I'm building a service allowing to connect to remote machine in order to diagnose/repair it. I would like to use MSMQ in it and wondering is it ok to assume that MSMQ will always work, so I don't need to consider it as one of problematic parts of the system?

I wish that equation be true:
MSMQ doesn't work ==  Machine/Windows is down

Thanks

Comment: I mean, MSMQ is reliable to a very large degree, but is anything really ever 100% reliable...?

Comment: So, you are asking if there is an oracle somewhere that knows the full set of bugs in MSMQ and the exact circumstances under which every single one of them can or cannot crash or otherwise affect its operation?

Comment: it's just software so it's never 100%. I hoped for reliable *enough* to assume though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's never okay to assume that software will never crash. If it's that important to you, use an alerting system to let you know if the MSMQ service stops.

However, you're probably not going to design something yourself that will have the features of MSMQ, and be more fault tolerant than MSMQ.

Comment: I thought about it and the very question is "if my alerting system will be more reliable than MSMQ", the problem seems to be recursive

Comment: That's not true unless both fail at the same time. If MSMQ fails, your alerting system should tell you. If it doesn't, you need a new alerting system. There is nothing else you can really do. Software fails. We can only deal with it the best we can.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to build your own alerting system. I mean, you can, but you don't have to. We've been using Argent and are moving to SCOM. I'm sure there are others.

Comment: you should just code it correctly then it will never fail. That's what I do.

Comment: @BobHorn I'm wondering if my question makes sense actually. How assuming that MSMQ will work is different from assuming that .NET will work?

Comment: Now you're losing me. .NET is just a framework of code that apps use so we don't have to rewrite everything ourselves. If you're seriously worried about .NET working, you should switch to another language. But that's not going to be any better, so I think you just need to trust what you're using unless you plan on writing an entire programming language yourself.

Comment: @BobHorn I definetely trust that .Net will not crash. That's why I asked that question. So I'm wondering if I can trust .Net, can I trust MSMQ same way. Or I should treat it different as it's a networking service, not framework of my app.

Comment: I wonder all of these to decide if I should use MSMQ or directly talk with my service but if I have same level of trust to .net and MSMQ I see no reason to think that MSMQ might fail and my own (queue-less) mechanism using .Net will not.

Comment: So, as long as MSMQ is local (no networking problems) it should work. I believe all that thread is quite meta and philosophical so it's not easy to answer it.

Comment: @BobHorn do you agree?

Comment: You're getting into architecture now. I don't think your decision to use MSMQ should be based on it crashing. You should google the reasons for using MSMQ, and if that fits what you want to achieve with your app, then use it. If not, don't.

Comment: I need queue and I know why :p however in that particular case I could trade it for safety. Anyway as I said I don't see reason why would I trust .net more than msmq so I will just ignore the fact it can crash and treat it as very unlikely